# How to find out, why serial communication stops?

Tags: process, port, communication, plc, scada

I am using Indusoft Web Studio v7.1 (a scada software) that runs on a com port. Everything goes well for half a day or even for a day. But after that it shows an error

```
error Initializing driver MODBU: Invalid Serial port
```

although the same serial port is selected in scada and system.

Then, how can I determine the process on a comPort running as I can't find anything in windows process explorer?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Zubair. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to describe the problem better. What's the name of the scada software? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please ask just one question at a time...

Comment: hi greenmarkeri am using Indusoft Web studio v7.1

Comment: Is your device "an energy analyzer omron km50-e whose output is Modbus rs-485" ? Do you use a icp module i-7563 which is rs485 to rs232 converter ? (https://www.indusoft.com/Support/Forums/aft/1685), but I see that I-7563 is a USB-RS485 converter (http://www.icpdas.com/root/product/solutions/industrial_communication/converter/i-7563.html).

Comment: no it is PowerLogic PM8000 schneider electric.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enable and disable de COM when you aren't using it. Using a Bool variable.
[Driver Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqIsb.png)

Disable field: Type a tag or an expression to enable and disable the communication of each MAIN DRIVER SHEET on the fly.
Type a value (or expression result) that is greater than zero to disable the MAIN DRIVER SHEET.
Type a zero (or leave this field blank) to enable the MAIN DRIVER SHEET.

Or try to stopt/start your driver runtime, if works you know that the problem is in the Indusoft and not a windows problem.

[Tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf254.png)